# Finding extremals which arise from a non-linear third order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to determine the extremals of the functional $F(x,y,y',y'') = (y')^2 + (y'')^2$.

I know that in this case the first integral satisfies

$$F - y' \left( F_{y'} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F_{y''}\right)-y''F_{y''}=k$$

where $k$ is a constant.

For the aforementioned functional, I can easily see that $F_{y'} = 2y'$ and that $F_{y''} = 2y''$, and furthermore $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F_{y''}=2y'''$.

If I put this into the equation satisfied by the extremal, we get
$$(y')^2 + (y'')^2 -y'(2y' - 2y''') - y''(2y'')=k$$

and it is then possible to re-write this as

$$(y')^2 + (y'')^2 = 2y'y''' - k$$

I am unsure what to do next. Is there a trick that I can use to solve this nonlinear third order ODE? I tried integrating both sides between 0 and 1 (as those are the two $x$-values that the boundary conditions specify) as I can see that the functional appears on the left hand side of the equation, but the exercise I am doing is asking for the extremals which implies that I need to find $y(x)$ rather than what the stationary value of the integral is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

$$
F(x,y,y',y'')= (y')^2+(y'')^2
$$

we have according to Euler-Lagrange conditions

$$
F_y-\left(F_{y'}\right)'+\left(F_{y''}\right)'' = -2(y^{(4)}-y'')=0
$$

hence

$$
y = C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}+C_3 x+ C_4
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I ended up using the formula for the first integral to try and find the extremal rather than simply solving the Euler-Lagrange equation... now it seems so obvious. Cheers!

Comment: Actually, you might want to double-check the Euler-Lagrange condition and plugging all the derivatives into it. I ended up getting $F_y = 0$, $(F_{y'})' = 2y''$ and $(F_{y''})'' = 2y'''$ which, when put into the condition, ends up with $$2(y'''' - y'') = 0$$ which has general solution $$y = C_1 e^{x} + C_2 e^{-x} + C_3 x + C_4$$. This seems to make sense from the complete version of the problem in the book - the boundary conditions do not involve "nice" angular numbers in $x$.

Still thanks though - your approache was nonetheless a lot more elegant than mine :-)

Comment: @omegaSQU4RED Thanks for the correction. I had made a change of sign.